# Magento 2 - Cookies are not secure

Tags: magento2, session

I was wondering if there is a setting for creating secure cookies on M2. I have a vulnerability check and it shown that cookies don't have "secure" tags.

Or do I need to override a core function?

Comment: ... any luck taking care of this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a persistent problem when a site gets scanned for PCI compliance. Issue seems to be going back quite a while: https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Need-suggestions-regarding-quot-Missing-Secure-Flag-From-SSL/td-p/19777

One hacky fix is suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792989/where-is-secure-tag-in-magento-cookie-on-ssl-secure-site